# CNN training accuracy drop suddenly from 94% into 48%

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am working in audio classification using CNN. The raining accuracy goes normally in an increasing manner till it reaches (94.9%) in epoch (61), then all the sudden in epoch (62) the training accuracy dropped to (48.37%). I don't know what is the problem that causes this.

```
37792/37792 [===========] - 1056s 28ms/step - loss: 0.1544 - acc: 0.9490
Epoch 61/100
37792/37792 [==========] - 1056s 28ms/step - loss: 8.3078 - acc: 0.4837
Epoch 62/100
.......................................................
```

Comment: This could be a data related issue, check if the training dataset has proper labels, besides how does it behave after 62nd epoch?

Comment: It behaves bad after 62 epoch.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I've just solved the problem by customising the default optimiser.`lr = 0.0001

beta_1 = 0.9
beta_2 = 0.999
opti = keras.optimizers.adam(lr=lr, beta_1=beta_1, beta_2=beta_2, epsilon=None, clipnorm=1.)`